# "Error Validating Application" on localhost

Tags: facebook, oauth, access-token

First of all what I am trying to do:

Updating the status and uploading photos to a Facebook Page as the page (not a user)

What I did:

1. I created an application
2. I granted the app permission to manage my pages via the `manage_pages` permission. Also granted offline access and stream publish permissions.
3. I connected to the Open Graph API and retrieved the `access_token` for the page I want to post as.

The error I am getting:

`{"error":{"message":Error validating application.","type":"OAuthException"}}`

How I am getting the error:

I am running the following command on my terminal using the access_token from step 3 above

`curl -F 'access_token=MY_TOKEN'\`
`-F 'message=Testing'\`
`https://graph.facebook.com/MY_APP_ID/feed`

I have read on some similar questions that this maybe because of not properly setting up the Application, in many cases they mention the domain as something important to setup, but as `localhost` I am not sure what should I complete as domain name. I tried with `localhost` still the same error.

Any tip in the right direction much appreciated

Note: I don't absolutely need to run the script from my shell, I can use a php solution also.

Comment: Did you figure out a solution for this?  I am having the same issue even though I'm sure my token is correct